# How to I translate a string from say english to japanese in TCL scripts

Tags: tcl

Here is a piece of code I'm trying to run

```
package require msgcat
::msgcat::mclocale ja_JP
puts [::msgcat::mcpreferences]
puts [::msgcat::mc hello ja_JP]
```

The output of this code is....

```
ja_jp ja {} 
hello
```

Since I've changed the locale in the code to `ja_JP` and since `::msgcat::mc src_sting` is expected to translate the source string to a language which is inclined with the locale settings. I expected the output to be

```
ja_jp ja {}
こんにちは
```

How do I get this output?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. That trick worked. I used pre existing $::tk_library msgs and it works. I'm pretty new to this TCL. Can I get help in creating my own custom script containing the translation messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the translations.  (If only it worked so automagically!)

```
::msgcat::mcset ja hello こんにちは
```

Note that putting any non-ascii character directly into a Tcl source file is
not recommended.  The message catalog should be stored in a separate file and
loaded using the appropriate msgcat command.  e.g.:

```
msgcat::mcload [file join [file dirname [info script]] msgs]
```

See the [msgcat manual page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/msgcat.htm) .

Comment: One point to note: message catalogs are always sourced as UTF-8, _regardless of system encoding._